# How to get the admin/creator of a repository using Github REST API v3

Tags: api, github, search, admin

I want to get the details of the person who created the repository using Github API. I got the repositories in my organization using:

```
https://github.example.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q=org:<name>
```

I got a list of 30 repositories within the organization with details in the following manner:

```
{
  "total_count": 40,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 3081286,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMDgxMjg2",
      "name": "Tetris",
      "full_name": "dtrupenn/Tetris",
      "owner": {
        "login": "dtrupenn",
        "id": 872147,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjg3MjE0Nw==",
        "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e7956084e75f239de85d3a31bc172ace?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/dtrupenn",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/dtrupenn/received_events",
        "type": "User"
      },
      "private": false,
      "html_url": "https://github.com/dtrupenn/Tetris",
      "description": "A C implementation of Tetris using Pennsim through LC4",
      "fork": false,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/dtrupenn/Tetris",
      "created_at": "2012-01-01T00:31:50Z",
      "updated_at": "2013-01-05T17:58:47Z",
      "pushed_at": "2012-01-01T00:37:02Z",
      "homepage": "",
      "size": 524,
      "stargazers_count": 1,
      "watchers_count": 1,
      "language": "Assembly",
      "forks_count": 0,
      "open_issues_count": 0,
      "master_branch": "master",
      "default_branch": "master",
      "score": 10.309712
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem I have right now is that the owner's id is always the same and it's equal to the organization name. I want the details of the creators. Is there any way I could do that? I tried searching everywhere, but I couldn't find any solution.